# I sent an email asking for a letter of request almost a week ago and have not received a response, thoughts on how to proceed during COVID?

Tags: application, recommendation-letter, email

I asked my two of my current Med school faculty for a LOR almost a week ago and I have got no response yet from either. It is making me pretty nervous and I am not sure what I should do now. I wouldn't regularly make this request over email, but our school is currently shut down because of COVID-19. For reference: I asked via email a week ago and the application is due May 1, so about 5 weeks ahead, both are doctors at our affiliated hospital, but in specialties not typically associated w handling the COVID crisis. My application will be much weaker without at least one of these two letters and there is no way the school will re-open before the due date. Any suggestions on how to proceed, or should I start preparing emails to other faculty as well? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With due respect: these people don’t work for you, and you have 5 weeks before deadline.
If they promised letters, one must presume they will write the letters at a time convenient to *them*.

If you have not heard with 10 days to go before deadline then ask again.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I should have probably specified more clearly in the original post that the faculty have not said yes or no to writing the letter yet. I understand that they have other duties, now more than ever, than to write me a recommendation. I'm just trying to prepare for whatever contingencies that may happen if they can't write one.

Comment: If they have not committed yet then wait a week (at most 2 weeks) and assume that no answer means no LOR.